# SQL Server : split a string based on space, into 1 column

Tags: split, sql-server-2014

I'm looking for a good method to split a string based on space\underscore into one columns.

**For example:**

```
string name = 'tom arnold lee ford'
into named_columns
```

and then do a query:

```
select name from named_columns
```

Output:

```
tom
arnold
lee
ford
```

Thank you...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

Comment: How is it help me? Dont understand

Comment: It is the same principle. You have space as sepratator. The question linked uses commas. But the rest is the same.